# How to Modify a specific Byte in an Interger

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have the following code -

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned int    u4Val       = 0xAABBCCDD;
    unsigned char   u1User_Val  = 0x00;

    int Byte_Location = 0;

    printf ("\n %08X \n", val);

    printf ("\n Enter Byte Location : ");
    scanf  ("%d", &Byte_Location);  /* Get - 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 */

    printf ("\n Enter Value to Write : ");
    scanf ("%02X", &u1User_Val);

    /*====== Code to Write on the Byte Location in u4Val ======*/

    printf ("\n %08X \n", u4Val);

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample IO**

- Case 1:

  Input:  Byte_Location = 0  and  Value = 0x54

  Output: 0x54BBCCDD
- Case 2:

  Input:  Byte_Location = 1  and  Value = 0x21

  Output: 0xAA21CCDD
- Case 3:

  Input:  Byte_Location = 2  and  Value = 0xFB

  Output: 0xAABBFBDD
- Case 4:

  Input:  Byte_Location = 3  and  Value = 0x32

  Output: 0xAABBCC32

Please help me to code on the pending part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cast to `char*` and use the subscript operator. Be aware of endianess, though.

Comment: @cad a cleaner and more portable solution would be bitshift/mask.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use unsigned bit shifts.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned ByteReplace(unsigned x, unsigned byte_index, unsigned char byte_new) {
  assert(sizeof x * CHAR_BIT >= 4 * 8);
  printf("Input: Byte_Location = %u and Value = 0x%02X\n", byte_index,
          byte_new);

  // Typically I'd expect byte_index to imply the least significant byte.  OP has otherwise
  byte_index = 3 - byte_index;

  unsigned mask = 0xFFu << byte_index * 8;
  unsigned y = (~mask & x) | (byte_new << byte_index * 8);
  printf("Output: 0x%08X\n", y);
  return y;
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned int u4Val = 0xAABBCCDD;
  ByteReplace(u4Val, 0, 0x54);
  ByteReplace(u4Val, 1, 0x21);
  ByteReplace(u4Val, 2, 0xFB);
  ByteReplace(u4Val, 3, 0x32);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Input: Byte_Location = 0 and Value = 0x54
Output: 0x54BBCCDD
Input: Byte_Location = 1 and Value = 0x21
Output: 0xAA21CCDD
Input: Byte_Location = 2 and Value = 0xFB
Output: 0xAABBFBDD
Input: Byte_Location = 3 and Value = 0x32
Output: 0xAABBCC32
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a;
((char*)&a)[0]=0x54
((char*)&a)[1]=0x21
((char*)&a)[2]=0xFB
((char*)&a)[3]=0x32
```

it is preferably to use bitwise shifting, but this one is easy to use and remember.

Comment: This will have different results on big and little endian systems.

Comment: well, i am not so sure, @Barmar do you think it does?

Comment: It will be `0x5421FB32` on big endian and `0x32FB2154` on little endian, but it is also undefined behaviour to access the value via `a` directly after this because of the strict aliasing rule. You also forgot the `;` at the end of the lines.